# Where can I download DroidEx.jar?

Tags: android, jar

Hi, I'm not able to find DroidEx.jar anywhere. Can anyone help me download this jar file? If not, is there any alternative to project device screen on Monitor or Projector?

Comment: The link provided everywhere for a download is http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android/web/DroidEx.jar, but it seems unavailable right now, and in some places it was taken down completely. I don't know if it's still available at all.

Comment: ya but page is down. is there any other repo ?

Comment: I've looked around, and they all point there. I don't think there is, but I'll keep an eye out and alert you if I find one.

Comment: hmm thanks a lot .. and do u knw any other tool for capturing the screen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DroidEx was replaced a long time ago by [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/2010/01/droidscreen/).

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi CommonsWare i've check a couple of your links for DroidEx but they don't seem to be there anymore. Is there an alternative software that will do the same? I just need to show the device's screen on a large screen. Thanks

Comment: @turtleboy: You'll want to use droid@screen, an improved replacement for my old DroidEx application: http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks alot, works fine. There is a bit of lag but it's fine. thanks

Comment: @turtleboy: You would have seen the same lag with DroidEx. It is a limitation of how quickly we can pull screenshots off of the device. For casual demos of fairly static screens, it works OK. For anything fancier than that, either use a device projector (e.g., an ELMO) or use a device with HDMI out that you can tie into a projector.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi, my boss is wanting to demo my app when meeting new customers. Is there a way to show the device's screen on a large screen eg TV, without downloading eclipse and the android sdk onto the laptop?

Comment: @turtleboy: If the device has HDMI-out, use it. Otherwise, I am not aware of a solution for you, other than to buy a device that does have HDMI-out... :-) Anything running Android 3.0 or higher and an HDMI port should work well for your purposes.

Comment: @CommonsWare brilliant i've got HTC ONE X and that's got an HDMI-out. He'll have to get a high end phone:) thanks again